How can I add a header to a network request in Playwright
When I use the page.goto method, I need to add a header to one of the network requests that are made. I have worked out how to deleted a header (below), but cannot work out how to add:
await page.route(url, (route, request) => {
    const originalHeaders = request.headers();

    delete originalHeaders['authorization'];

    route.continue({
        headers: originalHeaders,
    });
})


A minimal, complete example of the request you want to make and the full code you're using would be good. You can use httpbin to make it reproducible so it's clear how to answer exactly as you need.

Add a property to the header object like this:
await page.route(url, (route, request) => {
    const originalHeaders = request.headers();

    originalHeaders.newHeaderName = 'value'  // <-----

    route.continue({
        headers: originalHeaders,
    });
})

